# html - how to save selected option into database

Tags: php, html, html-select

i wanna ask something.
the case is about simple cart on php, i wanna add 'size' feature in my cart. I use select to show the option. how it can be input / save into database? in this case, i use table for my cart, not session because i still learn it.

first, this is my index about product

```
<?php 
include "customer.php";
include "conn.php"; 
echo"<h1>Product</h1>
 <ul>";
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prod");
while($d=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
    echo"<li>$d[name] : $d[price] || &nbsp;


                       <select id='size' name='size'>
                       <option value='S'>S</option>
                       <option value='M'>M</option>
                       <option value='L'>L</option>
                       <option value='XL'>XL</option>
                       <option value='XXL'>XXL</option>
                       </select>
                   </td></tr>

<a href='act_cart.php?id=$d[id]'>BUy</a></li>";
    }
echo"</ul>";
?>
```

---

---

this file act_cart.php

```
<?php 
include "customer.php"; //check customer login
include "conn.php"; // db


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id_prod FROM cart WHERE id_prod='$_GET[id]' AND 
id_user='$_SESSION[id_user]'");
$find=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($find==0){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO cart (id, id_user, id_prod, size, qty)
            VALUES (NULL,'$_SESSION[id_user]', '$_GET[id]', '$_GET[size]', 1)");
} else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE cart
            SET qty = qty + 1
            WHERE id_user ='$_SESSION[id_user]' AND id_prod='$_GET[id]'");       
}   
header('Location:cart.php');

?>
```

so, which method can i use to get the "size" then save into database?

Comment: Friendly note that [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is deprecated and officially removed since php 7.0. you should switch over to the more secure and robust [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) class or even [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). These classes are essential in your website security.

Comment: thanks you, i'll try to learn it after this problem solved. first time learn about programming

Comment: To be honest, I'd make the change now because mysqli also has [mysqli->error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and that will tell you your issue